# drop year and month and year from a date format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, string-to-datetime

so I want to convert this column from str to date format ,i used the following
`df["Time"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Time"],format='%H:%M')`

OUTPUT:
0     1900-01-01 02:29:00
1     1900-01-01 06:52:00
2     1900-01-01 10:23:00
3     1900-01-01 12:59:00
.
.
.
Name: Time, Length: 736, dtype: datetime64[ns]

why does it show me the year,month and day even tho i didnt specify it?how can i remove it?

the string format : "02:29"

`df["Time"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Time"],format='%H:%M')`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? datetime is not a *format*, it's a data type. Also, in pandas, there is only the datetime data type built-in, no separate date or time (as in "native" Python). That's why it's showing year/month/date as well, if you parse string to datetime. 1900-01-01 is the default if you don't specify anything.

Answer (score 0):

format will be considered as your input format not the values you want to consider. Try the below line

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format= '%H:%M' ).dt.time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime property [dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) to get the time after the conversion, like so:

```
df["Time"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Time"],format='%H:%M').dt.time
```